# Problem with shortcuts in KDE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, kde, manjaro, firefox

I'm facing something weird since yesterday after I manipulated some shortcuts in **Manjaro custom shortcuts**.

Now when I use **Ctrl + LeftArrow** in **Firefox**, it navigates me to previous active tab in addition to going backward in words.

I reverted my changes back, but nothing solved. (Ctrl + RightArrow is working properly!)

Is this normal? Does Firefox have an editable keymap somewhere?

In fact, I'm looking for more learning than trying to solve this problem.

*Thanks in advance*

Comment: Just to know that everything is up to date and Kernel version is 5.17.1-3.